# Data Explorer query editor ignores Shift+Space

Tags: bug, data-explorer, editor, status-completed

The query editor in the Data Explorer does not insert a space if the user types Shift+Space. This is very annoying for those of us who prefer to type SQL keywords in upper-case. Sometimes I haven't let go of the shift key until after I type the space, or sometimes there are two keywords in a row (i.e. `ORDER BY`).

Comment: PS: I really don't care whether it enters an upper-case space or a lower-case space. ;)

Comment: done, I really do not know why code mirror chose those defaults, it is confusing, I just deleted the code for shift space handling

Comment: note I fixed this ... again ... yesterday. It was working for ie/firefox but was broken on webkit.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I write SQL keywords in upper case as well, so I'd love to see this fixed.

In fact the behaviour is even more annoying if you've pasted in a query with indentation that you're going to edit -- pressing Shift+Space actually *unindents* the current line completely.

Comment: yerp I got rid of all those sill "electric keys" this should not happen anymore

Comment: @waffles: I noticed the last time I was on there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CAPSLOCK?

Comment: Who needs CAPSLOCK when you have STICKY KEYS?